# Recharts import fail (v2.4.2)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, recharts

After ugprading recharts from **2.2.0** to **2.4.2** in a react+webpack project, it fails with the following message:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/recharts/es6/util/ChartUtils.js 741:14-24
export 'stack' (imported as 'shapeStack') was not found in 'victory-vendor/d3-shape' (module has no exports)
 @ ./node_modules/recharts/es6/component/LabelList.js 26:0-55 46:64-81
 @ ./node_modules/recharts/es6/index.js 13:0-50 13:0-50
 @ ./src/pages/xxx.tsx 9:0-110 155:36-55 158:45-54 160:47-60 162:40-45 162:70-76 162:101-108 162:133-138 164:40-44
 @ ./src/pages/yyy.tsx 10:0-41 147:177-188
 @ ./src/routes.tsx 395:9-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 20:0-30 87:119-125
 @ ./src/index.tsx 8:0-24 12:30-33
```

The code is imported like this:

```
import {
  CartesianGrid,
  Legend,
  Line, LineChart, ResponsiveContainer, Tooltip, XAxis, YAxis,
} from 'recharts';
```

When trying the same version in a blank vite project, it works out of the box.
Replicating the issue is hard as the project contains many internal packages which bring in various dependencies.

Is it a configuration error in webpack perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried to delete node_modules and reinstalling all the packages?